# Using clap with multiple commands sharing subcommand syntax/common args

Tags: rust, command-line, command-line-interface, clap

I've been using Clap to write a command line tool in Rust. The design that makes most sense for this project is to have multiple commands, each containing roughly the same subcommands that have different flags, but some overlap of "common args." For example, suppose I wanted the following behavior:

```
MyTool Command1 Mode1 -f "some flag" -n 2
MyTool Command1 Mode2 -d "different" -b "behavior"
MyTool Command2 Mode1 -f "similar flag" -n 5 -x
```

I'm having trouble organizing the code properly to simulate this sort of thing.

I tried setting up my code like so:

```
#[derive(Parser, Debug)]
pub struct Arguments {
    #[command(subcommand)]
    pub command: Command,
}

#[derive(Subcommand, Debug)]
pub enum Command {
    Command1(Command1Args),
    Command2(Command2Args),
}

#[derive(Subcommand, Debug)]
pub enum Mode {
    Mode1(Mode1Args),
    Mode2(Mode2Args)
}

#[derive(Args, Debug)]
pub struct Command1Args {
    #[clap(subcommand)]
    pub mode: Mode
}

...
```

But this starts to feel a little clunky and unwieldy for a number of reasons:

1. It's hard to run the correct functions for the command depending on the "mode" setting. I can write the `impl` blocks for each mode, but it'd be nice to be able to match the `Mode` directly from parsing the top level arguments without having to match through all of the `Command` types manually in the `main` function, and then call the right method through a shared trait. I looked into `enum_dispatch` to see if it would help, but I couldn't seen to get it to work.
2. I tried using generics in my `Mode` enum and then created vacuous traits to distinguish between the different modes. This seems like it would work, but the code becomes a bit bloated in having to make multiple mode-based args structs for each command, and then still doing a bunch of manual matching.

Ideally, I'd like to be able to just have one trait that each command implements, and pick which of its corresponding methods to run based on the `Mode`. I'd really like to be able to do something like this in my `main`:

```
match &args.mode {
    Mode1 => &args.command.mode1_method(),
    Mode2 => &args.command.mode2_method()
}
```

instead of having to match through each of the different `&args.command` possible values. Here each of the possible `command`s would implement a trait to have each of their own version of the `mode_method`.

Stylistically, I'd really prefer to implement the `Mode` as a subcommand rather than a separate flag and use arg groups to control for incompatible arguments, as that would make more semantic sense on the command line for that to follow directly after the command, and would help make it cleaner to maintain separation of the different flags for the different modes. For the application I want, essentially the different `Mode`s are a "Server" mode and a "Client" mode, so they don't make as much sense to me to put them on the same level as a separate flag.

I've read [some](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75514455/how-to-parse-common-subcommand-arguments-with-clap-in-rust) [other](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76408952/rust-clap-re-use-same-arguments-in-different-subcommand) [questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73357989/clap-subcommands-over-multiple-rs-files) that seem similar at a glance but I don't think apply to this use case. I think either of the ideas I mentioned above might work, but they're starting to feel a little tricky to the point I might be missing some key ideas, so hope some more experienced programmers here can make some suggestions. Thanks!

Comment: I'd probably write a `Command::mode(&self) -> &Mode` accessor that returns the mode. `Option<&Mode>` in case it's not on all commands. That way you can almost write your desired syntax with an added `command` and some extra parentheses.

Comment: The tricky thing there is that the types in `Command` are wrappers around different `Args` types, which then themselves have a `Mode` field. It's possible I could implement a trait for each of them with a `get_mode` method, but then the enum wouldn't inherit it automatically, and I'd still have to do a big manual match over all the commands (which is maybe the best way to do it anyway...)